# HTTP Error 404.0 when editing User in ASP.Net - MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, edit

I'm pretty new to programming in C#, ASP.NET and the MVC framework so I'm still trying to figure everything out with some help from e-books and of course the internet.

I'm making a test web application to see if I understand some of the basics of programming in ASP.NET - MVC and I started with the default MVC template that you get when you start a new project in Visual Studio. With this in mind you should know that this template already has a working User login and register function and after I connected this to my database I could register as much user as I want and login with these user. To take it a little bit further I want to edit the user properties after the account is registered. After I addes the code below, I can see my user information and I can edit them, but when i press the Save button I get the following error message:

http://puu.sh/pl5L5/b70da8b40d.png

Please keep in mind that I'm a newbie so my apologizes if this question is rather stupid. Thanks in advance!

**THE CODE**

A new view under the ManageController:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditUser", "Manage", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <h4>Edit User Form.</h4>
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>@(prop.DisplayName ?? prop.PropertyName)</label>
            @if (prop.PropertyName == "Description")
            {
                @Html.TextArea(prop.PropertyName, null, new { @class = "form-control", rows = 5 })
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.TextBox(prop.PropertyName, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
            }
            @Html.ValidationMessage(prop.PropertyName)
        </div>
    }
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <input type="submit" value="Opslaan" class="btn btn-primary" />
        @Html.ActionLink("Cancel and return to List", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
    </div>
}
```

A new EditUserViewModel:

```
public class EditUserViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Display(Name = "Voornaam")] //FirstName
    public string Voornaam { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Display(Name = "Achternaam")] //LastName
    public string Achternaam { get; set; }

    public string Telefoonnummer { get; set; } //Phonenumber
}
```

And 2 new methods in the ManageController:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> EditUser(string id)
    {
        id = this.User.Identity.GetUserId();
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        var userRoles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);

        return View(new EditUserViewModel()
        {
            Email = user.Email,
            Voornaam = user.Voornaam,
            Achternaam = user.Achternaam,
            Telefoonnummer = user.PhoneNumber
        });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> EditUser([Bind(Include = "Id, Email, Voornaam, Achternaam, Telefoonnummer")]EditUserViewModel editUser)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(editUser.Id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            user.UserName = editUser.Email;
            user.Email = editUser.Email;
            user.Voornaam = editUser.Voornaam;
            user.Achternaam = editUser.Achternaam;
            user.VolledigeNaam = editUser.Email;
            user.PhoneNumber = editUser.Telefoonnummer;

            await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Something failed.");
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: you have only two fields in your razor view inside the form and your action inside the controller expects more than two, so it cannot mapped the correct action during postback

Comment: @Katana, the foreach goes to every property in the Model and shows this as a field. So I have a field for every property that I use.

Comment: So your 404 is generated by your own code? Have you tried stepping through it, and verifying that your model is binding correctly? Check what the TextBox id values are rendered as in the html.

Answer (score 0):

After searching and searching and searching I finally found the problem. In the ManageController in the EditUser method is had following code:

```
    return View(new EditUserViewModel()
    {
        Email = user.Email,
        Voornaam = user.Voornaam,
        Achternaam = user.Achternaam,
        Telefoonnummer = user.PhoneNumber
    })
```

But the problem was that the ID field didn't get the value of the user. I forgot this because I didn't want the users to be able to edit their ID. So the code should be:

```
    return View(new EditUserViewModel()
    {
        Id = user.Id
        Email = user.Email,
        Voornaam = user.Voornaam,
        Achternaam = user.Achternaam,
        Telefoonnummer = user.PhoneNumber
    })
```